Securing In-App Purchases for Guest and Logged-in Players in a Flutter and Node.js Real-Time Game
I am developing a real-time game with Flutter as the frontend and Node.js as the backend. The game includes a shop UI where players can buy coins, gems, and avatars. Players can purchase gems using virtual coins and avatars using virtual gems. For each item, the UI displays its price in either virtual gems or coins. Data storage varies based on the player's status (guest or logged in).
Current Implementation:
For guest players, data is stored locally using sqflite. The purchase process is handled entirely on the frontend to reduce server costs. Here’s the method for buying gems:
Dart

void buyGems(int coins, int gems) async {
    showErrMsg(coins, user.userData.coins, "no_coins_for_bundle_msg");
    user.userData.coins = user.userData.coins - coins;
    user.userData.gems += gems;
    await user.saveOrUpdateUserInLocalDb(user.userData);
}

For logged-in players, data is stored both locally (sqflite) and on the server (MySQL). The backend handles the purchase process to ensure security. The steps are:
-The player sends a request to the server.
-The server checks if the player has enough coins.
-The server retrieves the bundle's price and amount from environment variables.
-The server updates the player's data in the MySQL database.
-The server responds to the client.
-The client updates the local database upon a successful response.
Security for Guest Players: Since the calculation and data update are handled on the frontend, there's a risk of players accessing and modifying the Flutter files to manipulate their data.
Server Resource Management: Moving all calculations to the backend for security reasons can increase server load and costs, which is a concern given the limited budget.

If the calculations are only the calculations shown in the Dart code, they are small enough to be moved to the server, it will add barely any delay to the server code, we are talking most of the time less than 50ms, depending on hardware it may go up to a hundred ms, most likely not more than 150ms.

If something can be done server-side, it most likely should be, there is no reason to move jobs which should be done on the server, to the client, especially when it involves data security.
